# Reading an image as byte array with Android: skImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC Web Service that returns an image as a byte array. The output is in json format. The format is png
Here's the code snippet for the image.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(caminho.replace("/", "//")));
                imagem = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer

()).getData();
```

When I run the server, this is the output:

[{"id":0,"caminhoMDPI":null,"caminhoHDPI":"C:/Users/Marcos/Pictures/postos/drawable-

mdpi/esso_logo.png","caminhoXHDPI":null,"caminhoXXHDPI":null,"imagem":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....]

Eventually, other symbols appear on the "imagem" field. I suppose this is right, but I'm not

sure.

On my Android app, I have a routine to download the image and store it as a blob in the database. I receive the json format and transform it into a class with jackson. I've logged the "imagem" field and it looks the same.

My problem is that I can't transform it into an image. Here's the code snippet:

```
byte[] img_bandeira = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("img_bandeira"));
        Bitmap bmpBandeira = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img_bandeira, 0, img_bandeira.length);
        ImageView ivBandeira = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBandeira);
        ivBandeira.setImageBitmap(bmpBandeira);
```

All I get is a message: skImageDecoder::Factory returned null.

I've looked at other similar posts, tried to change some lines, but nothing happened. I don't know what's going on here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. In the server, the image should be sent like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(caminho.replace("/", "//")));
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
                baos.flush();
                String base64String = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
                baos.close();
```

In my app, it should be read like this:

```
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] imageArray) {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageArray);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Thank you, everybody ;)